# Git ignore files but repo site doesn't change

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I wanted to apply a .gitignore file on an existing repository but neither the repository size is changing nor the amount of files beeing pushed.

What I did was:

1. Create .gitignore on root path
2. Add files/path to that file
3. git rm -r --cached . To removed all tracked files
4. git add . <- At this point git should apply the ignore file?
5. git commit

But when I do a `git count-objects -v -H` it tells me: `size-pack: 2.15GB`.
When I push the repo it takes a huge amount of time so I expect that git realy tries to push this 2GB monster.

After looking at the output of `git status --ignored` I see the folders I want to ignore which means that git knows they shouldn't be tracked?

My question is how I can keep my files locally, no track certain files/folders from the `git count-objects` command and prevent git from pushing said folder to my online repository.

## edit

after doing a `git repack` the output of `git count-objects -v -H` displays  `size-pack: 4.31GB`.

## edit

Under that path `.git\objects\pack` is a file exactly the same size as `git count-objects -v -H` tells me. After saving the file to a different place and removing it the repository size is ~3MiB which is more likely.
But it isn't easy as that beacuse now Git tells me that my branches are not pointing to a valid object.

```
error: Could not read 605553ce8c011122449e86a5a5c4dfee846622b7
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 0ac59e4f558299f981220f6b84e56584f98a2c38
error: failed to run repack
vagrant@vbox:/var/www$ git branch -rd origin/test-upgrade-branch
error: refs/heads/development does not point to a valid object!
```

Comment: *git add . <- At this point git should apply the ignore file?* Actually, the .gitignore is applied the moment when you save the file

Comment: You should add and commit `.gitignore` file first for it to be effective.

Comment: I tried that one too and the .gitignore file is getting applied but still the count-objects method return ~4GB.

Comment: Did you add the files prior to that? If so you can't remove them that way from the repository all together. You should look at https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ to remove those from git objects. Or use `git-filter-branch` to do it using a git command.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think the problem is not that I have one or two large files it's ocuring to me that I have a problem with the history of my repository. I did a `git -r --cached .` and modified my `.gitignore`. After that I added and commited the `.gitignore` and then added and commited the files again which is working. But the size still remains at ~4GiB.

Comment: You need to know that once added, a file never disappear from git objects (therefore from repository), unless you erase them using `git-filter-branch` or `BFG`

Answer (score -1):

Changes would happen in repository when you push the changes

```
git push origin master
```

Then, it should work as expected.

Comment: Well the problem is that git is trying to push this ~2GB repository which really isn't what I want.